# Why is tr.archive.ubuntu.com down?

Tags: networking, apt, server, updates

I'm from Turkey and updating and or such was working before until today or the other day it broke. It was saying a temporary DNS error when connecting to tr.archive.ubuntu.com. I tried connecting to there from my browser and my phone and it seems I can't.

Tried with cellular data too in case my router is blocking it or such but same. I've also tried it in a site like down detector or something and it was saying it is not just you - tr.archive.ubuntu.com is down. I've fixed apt update etc. not working by changing the update server from my country to main server.

Though that made downloads slower, so I've used "Select the best server" and it selected one of the mirrors from my local providers.

The thing is though, I'm curios. Why is the Ubuntu's official servers for my country are down and I must use another mirror? Even though it verifies hashes or something I want to use the tr.archive.ubuntu.com. Why it is down?

Comment: No one here can answer that were do not work for the company.

Comment: Hasn't Turkey been playing "shutdown the internet so the world won't see, and the people can't organize" game?

Answer (score 1):

Mirrors are run by third parties. The come & go and move over time. You can see the full list of mirrors [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors). Simply select a different mirror from the list, or use the "Select the best server" to find the most optimal one for you.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the server worked for me. To do this, type the command below to the terminal.

```
xdg-open /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then you should choose the server as in the picture (just change the *Download from* option to *Main server*).

[image: Software & Updates menu]